# Can sequential stream operations have side-effects?

Tags: java, java-stream, side-effects

I'm trying to stream a limited number of values into a set, but I need to verify that they're new elements before applying the limit. For example:

```
Set<Integer> destination = ... 
Set<Integer> source = ...
source.stream()
        .filter(i -> !destination.contains(i))
        .limit(10)
        .forEach(destination::add);
```

But the redundant `contains()` check is bothering me, since `add()` can both add the element *and* report whether it's new to the collection. So I was thinking of doing this:

```
source.stream()
        .filter(destination::add)
        .limit(10)
        .forEach(i -> {});    // no-op terminal operation to force evaluation
```

Ignoring the hacky terminal operation, there's the problem of using a filter operation with a side-effect, which is generally discouraged. I understand why it would be unsafe to use `map()` and `filter()` with side-effects on parallel streams. My question is, would it be acceptable on a sequential stream, as in this case? If not, why not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't a fundamental problem with side effects and sequential streams, but the second implementation above is invalid, because the stream API doesn't guarantee that each stage will be executed on each element *in turn*.

In the second implementation, more than 10 elements may be added to `destination` before the limit is applied.  Your no-op forEach will only see 10, but you may end up with more in the set.

In addition to streams, java has looping constructs like `for` and `while` that can make it easy to express things like this.

If you *must* use streams, you can do it like this:

```
int maxSize = destination.size()+10;
source.stream().allMatch(x -> destination.size()<maxsize && (destination.add(x)||true));
```

The `allMatch` will stop the iteration as soon as the predicate returns false.

Comment: I think you've slightly misunderstood my scenario. `source` is a set, so it contains no duplicate elements. I'm trying to make sure that we're adding elements from `source` that don't *already* exist in `destination`. So I think the first solution would still work. But your overall point is an interesting one, namely that a stream element might not travel through the entire pipeline at once. Do you have a source for that, or are you relying on the lack of documentation to the contrary?

Comment: Lack of documentation to the contrary, *and* the fact that lots of optimizations on streams involve processing elements in chunks.  The code you've written appears to work today, but it relies on things that might very well change in new Java versions or other implementations.

Comment: I did indeed misunderstand the purpose of the check.  I edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Actually the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) does explicitly say that certain stateful operations like `sorted()` would have to be applied to multiple elements at once, and I guess it's not a far stretch to say some implementation might choose to do so for a stateless operation as well. Accepting this answer unless and until I find evidence to the contrary.

Comment: If you want an example, where this fails: with `Stream.of(source).flatMap(Set::stream) .filter(destination::add).limit(10).forEach(i -> {});`, the limit is ineffective. (While `forEach`’s action is correctly invoked at most ten times, of course)

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you:

```
package be.objectsmith;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Playground {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        copy(
            IntStream.range(1, 20).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet()),
            new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(2, 5)));
        copy(
            IntStream.range(1, 5).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet()),
            new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(2, 5)));
    }

    private static void copy(Set<Integer> source, Set<Integer> destination) {
        source
            .stream()
            .map(destination::add)
            .filter(resultOfAdding -> resultOfAdding)
            .limit(10)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());  // Need a terminal operation
        System.out.println("source = " + source);
        System.out.println("destination = " + destination);
    }

}
```

Running this class wil print:

```
source = [1, 2, 3, 4]
destination = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
destination = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

As you can see, it has only added 10 elements.
The second call demonstrates that it also works if you there are less than 10 elements to add.

Comment: This is just a more complicated version of the 2nd implementation in the question, breaking up filter(destination::add) into two operations.

Comment: @MattTimmermans It's a fix of the 2nd implementation, and it does exactly what the OP asks for : make use of the fact that `Set.add()` itself reports if it was a new element. Then it just needs to count and limit to succesful additions. I would even replace the terminal operation with `.count()`. All in all I would still prefer the first implementation; that `add` reports success is a convenience, which allows some cases to be expressed more elegantly, here however I only see added inconvenience

Comment: @bowmore what does it fix?  The original also works with the given test cases, makes use of the return from Set::add, and has no problems that aren't also in this answer.

Comment: @MattTimmermans had a second look at that original, you're right